# volume involving cross section

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the region with base enclosed by $y = x^2$ and $y = 3$ and cross sections perpendicular to the $y$-axis are rectangles of height $y^2$.

I sketched the graph and set-up the integral: $$\int_0^3 y^2(\sqrt{y} -3) dy$$ but I got a negative volume.. can someone tell me where I went wrong? I tried putting it as $2\sqrt{y}$ instead of $\sqrt{y} -3$ as I used the rule "right function -  left function", is this rather reasonable than the first one?.. please help. Thank you!

Comment: The base of the rectangle corresponding to the slice at $(0,y)$ has length $2\sqrt y.$

Comment: so it should be $$\int_0^3 y^2(2\sqrt{y}) dy $$ right?